# String to List Interpreter in List Prolog stuck on 2 items

Tags: string, list, prolog, interpreter

I wrote a programming language called List Prolog (in which predicates start with `[n,predicate_name]` and variables are `[v,variable_name]`), and am having trouble with getting some code (an algorithm with definite clause grammars, which takes a string and converts it to a Prolog term, or list of lists, etc.) to work with a query with n, not just 2 items per list (in the string).

As an aside, List Prolog is different from Prolog because it contains grammars which require the user to write their own base cases, similar to an interpreter written in C, i.e.

```
          [[n,compound213],["","",[v,t],[v,t]]],

          [[n,compound213],[[v,u],[v,u],[v,t],[v,t]]],
```

In the query, `[[n,grammar1],["[[\"aa\",b],1]",[v,t]]]` works, i.e.  where just 2 items i.e. `[\"aa\",b]` that can be converted as part of the string, but not a greater number than this, i.e. `[\"aa\",b,\"c\",[]]`, so `[[n,grammar1],["[[\"aa\",b,\"c\",[]],1]",[v,t]]]` doesn't work.

Note: the algorithm is meant to take a string such as `"[\"a\",b,3]"` and return a term, i.e. `["a",b,3]`, containing strings, atoms, numbers, empty lists and lists of more of these.

```
% The query:

test(15,[[n,grammar1],["[[\"aa\",b,\"c\",[]],1]",[v,t]]],

% The code:

[
          [[n,grammar1],[[v,u],[v,t]],":-",
          [
                     [[n,compound],[[v,u],"",[],[v,t]]]
          ]
          ],

          [[n,compound213],["","",[v,t],[v,t]]],

          [[n,compound213],[[v,u],[v,u],[v,t],[v,t]]],

          [[n,compound],[[v,t],[v,u]],"->",
          ["[","]",
          [[n,compound213],[[v,t],[v,u]]]]],

          [[n,compound],[[v,t],[v,u]],"->",
          ["[",[[n,compound21],[[v,t],[v,v]]],"]",
          [[n,compound213],[[v,v],[v,u]]]]],

          [[n,compound212],["","",[v,t],[v,t]]],

          [[n,compound212],[[v,u],[v,u],[v,t],[v,t]]],

          [[n,compound21],[[v,t],[v,u]],"->",
          [[[n,item],[[v,i]]],
          % [[n,lookahead],["]"]],
          [[n,code],[[n,wrap],[[v,i],[v,itemname1]]],
          [[n,append],[[v,t],[v,itemname1],[v,v]]]],
          [[n,compound212],[[v,v],[v,u]]]]],

          [[n,compound21],[[v,t],[v,u]],"->",
          [[[n,item],[[v,i]]],",",
          
          %[[n,code],[[n,trace]]],
          
          [[n,compound21],[[],[v,compound1name]]],
          [[n,code],[[n,wrap],[[v,i],[v,itemname1]]],
          [[n,append],[[v,t],[v,itemname1],[v,v]]],
          [[n,append],[[v,v],[v,compound1name],[v,u]]]]]],

          [[n,item],[[v,t]],"->",["\"",[[n,word21],["",[v,t]]],
            "\""]],

          [[n,item],[[v,t]],"->",
          [[[n,number21],["",[v,u]]],[[n,code],
          [[n,stringtonumber],[[v,u],[v,t]]]]]],

          [[n,item],[[v,t]],"->",[[[n,word21_atom],["",[v,t1]]],
          [[n,code],[[n,atom_string],[[v,t],[v,t1]]]]]], % atoms

          [[n,item],[[v,t]],"->",[[[n,compound],[[],[v,t]]]]],

          [[n,number212],["","",[v,t],[v,t]]],

          [[n,number212],[[v,u],[v,u],[v,t],[v,t]]],

          [[n,number21],[[v,t],[v,u]],"->",
          [[v,a],[[n,commaorrightbracketnext]],
          [[n,code],[[n,stringtonumber],[[v,a],[v,a1]]],
          [[n,number],[[v,a1]]],
          [[n,stringconcat],[[v,t],[v,a],[v,v]]]],
          [[n,number212],[[v,v],[v,u]]]]],

          [[n,number21],[[v,t],[v,u]],"->",
          [[v,a],
          [[n,code],[[n,stringtonumber],[[v,a],[v,a1]]],
          [[n,number],[[v,a1]]],
          [[n,stringconcat],[[v,t],[v,a],[v,v]]]],
          [[n,number21],["",[v,numberstring]]],
          [[n,code],[[n,stringconcat],
          [[v,v],[v,numberstring],[v,u]]]]]],

          [[n,word212],["","",[v,t],[v,t]]],

          [[n,word212],[[v,u],[v,u],[v,t],[v,t]]],

          [[n,word21],[[v,t],[v,u]],"->",
          [[v,a],[[n,quote_next]],
          [[n,code],
          [[n,not],[[[n,=],[[v,a],"\""]]]],
          [[n,stringconcat],[[v,t],[v,a],[v,v]]]],
          [[n,word212],[[v,v],[v,u]]]]],

          [[n,word21],[[v,t],[v,u]],"->",
          [[v,a],
          [[n,code],
          [[n,not],[[[n,=],[[v,a],"\""]]]],
          [[n,stringconcat],[[v,t],[v,a],[v,v]]]],
          [[n,word21],["",[v,wordstring]]],
          [[n,code],
          [[n,stringconcat],[[v,v],[v,wordstring],[v,u]]]]]],


          [[n,word212_atom],["","",[v,t],[v,t]]],

          [[n,word212_atom],[[v,u],[v,u],[v,t],[v,t]]],

          [[n,word21_atom],[[v,t],[v,u]],"->",
          [[v,a],[[n,commaorrightbracketnext]],
          [[n,code],
          [[n,not],[[[n,=],[[v,a],"\""]]]],
          [[n,not],[[[n,=],[[v,a],"["]]]],
          [[n,not],[[[n,=],[[v,a],"]"]]]],
          [[n,stringconcat],[[v,t],[v,a],[v,v]]]],
          [[n,word212_atom],[[v,v],[v,u]]]]],

          [[n,word21_atom],[[v,t],[v,u]],"->",
          [[v,a],
          [[n,code],
          [[n,not],[[[n,=],[[v,a],"\""]]]],
          [[n,not],[[[n,=],[[v,a],"["]]]],
          [[n,not],[[[n,=],[[v,a],"]"]]]],
          [[n,stringconcat],[[v,t],[v,a],[v,v]]]],
          [[n,word21_atom],["",[v,wordstring]]],
          [[n,code],
          [[n,stringconcat],[[v,v],[v,wordstring],[v,u]]]]]],
          
          [[n,commaorrightbracketnext],"->",
          [[[n,lookahead],[","]]]],

          [[n,commaorrightbracketnext],"->",
          [[[n,lookahead],["]"]]]],
          
          [[n,quote_next],"->",
          [[[n,lookahead],["\""]]]],

          
          [[n,lookahead],[[v,a],[v,a],[v,b]],":-",
          [[[n,stringconcat],[[v,b],[v,d],[v,a]]]]]
],

% The desired result:

[[[[v,t],[["aa",b,"c",[]],1]]]]).
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the code by uncommenting the line:

```
[[n,lookahead],["]"]],
```

after uncommenting the line to switch on debug,

```
[[n,code],[[n,trace]]],
```

which revealed that without the lookahead statement to check whether the next character is "]", the code followed the clause it was in after more than 2 items by mistake, failing, and with the lookahead statement, the clause it was in succeeded only at the end of a list of n items.